# How to get DB username in PL/Python function

Tags: python, postgresql, greenplum

I have a  PL/Python function like below

```
create function pl_python (database character)
returns character varying as

$BODY$

import subprocess
import getpass
import os

   return getpass.getuser()

$BODY$
 language plpythonu volatile
```

I am executing above function by connecting to greenplum database as XYZ user through pgadmin III

```
Select * from pl_python ('database')
```

Above function is returning the admin username not the username of the user who is executing the function. I need the username of the user who is executing the function

Current result: gpadmin

Expected result : XYZ

Thanks in Advance

Adding postgresql tag as the syntax might work in greenplum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Database Access Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html#idm46046859142368). Note, that you have to be connected to a database to get the current user, so the argument of the function makes a little sense.

```
create or replace function py_current_user()
    returns text
    language plpython3u
as $$
    res = plpy.execute("select current_user")
    return res[0]["current_user"]
$$;
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank You